# Java thread program exits before for loop (server side of program) (Eclipse using Mac Terminal/command line arguments)

Tags: java, eclipse, cmd

I trying to create a program that is supposed to send and receive text messages (UTF-8 strings).

For this error, I am working on the server side

The command line arguments for the server would be something like

```
java DirectMessengerServer -l 6021
```

[image: Missing print statments]

The problem with this screenshot is that "Try block begins" is not being printed out (which is the line being ignored later in the code).

Code of DirectMessengerServer.java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.*;
public class DirectMessengerServer
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        Thread Server = new Thread () 
        {
              public void run ()
              {   
                    System.out.println("Server thread is now running");
                    ServerSocket server_socket = null;
                    Socket client_socket;
                    String message1;

                    for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
                    {
                        if(args[0] == "-l")
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                System.out.println("Try block begins..");
                                int port_number1= Integer.valueOf(args[1]);
                                ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(port_number1);
                                System.out.println("Listening for connections..");
                                Socket socket = listener.accept();
                                client_socket= server_socket.accept();
                                BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client_socket.getInputStream(), "UTF8"));
                                PrintWriter output= new PrintWriter( client_socket.getOutputStream(), true );
                                String input_line= reader.readLine();
                                System.out.println( "Received from client: " );
                                System.out.println( input_line );
                                output.println( input_line );
                            }
                            catch ( Exception e )
                            {
                                System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
                            }
                            //server.close();
                        }
                    }
              }
        };
        Server.start();
    }
}
```

My question is why does the program stop without executing the try block and/or why is the "Try block begins" not being executed?

Comment: You are comparing strings with '==' instead of `equals()`

Comment: You are looking through the arguments, and then checking the first argument each time for referential equality. If you think about it this does not make sense.

Comment: Also, why are you running this in a separate thread?  It can simply be run on the program's main thread and would yield the same result.

Comment: @nachokk thank you I believe you're right, i'll make the change now
Kiskae is there a way to write the code so that I check only once (somehow I also need to check if -l is present or not.., should the for loop be replaced with an if statement perhaps?)

Comment: @JacobG. I would like to know how to start and stop threads to practice the syntax of running separate threads if that makes sense

Comment: @Eric Gotcha, I just want to make sure that it doesn't confuse others!

Comment: The program executes the try block now, thank you I believe this question is now solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two remarks:

1. As you assume that the '-l' parameter maps to `arg[0]`, make sure that you enter '-l' parameter before the port number parameter
2. Use `"-l".equals(arg[0])` instead of `args[0] == "-l"` as this is the proper way in Java to check if two strings have the same contents